# Notify me when I add Firebase realtime to list

Tags: firebase

I would like to get a notification when I create a new list in the database. I'm using Firebase realtime, this is the code I made but every time I open the activity it reads all the list. Do you have ideas?

This is my code

```
val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference()
reference.child("eistogodadalt").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
  override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    val children = dataSnapshot.children

    children.forEach {
      if (it.toString() == "") {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "arrivato nuovo post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
  }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to get a notification when I create a new list in the database"?

Comment: I would like that when I insert a new group of data, a notification arrives to all the apps. practically every time I post a news, a notification must arrive to the users of the app

Comment: Ok, then please share the code that is related to cloud messaging, and indicate what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: the code shared above. For now it was enough for me in simple toast. when i open the activity it comes out for every id , i wanted this not to happen but it should only come out when i change or create a new id

Answer (score 0):

This is my code excuse me

```
val firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference()
reference.child("eistogodadalt").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
  override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    val children = dataSnapshot.children

    children.forEach {
      Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "arrivato nuovo post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
  }
  override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
  }
})
```

Comment: What's the difference between this code and the code posted in your question?